# Best PHP Webserver for Development

Tags: php, webserver

I'm starting to work with PHP more these days and I've been wondering what the best PHP webserver might be for a dev environment. Ideally, it would be easy to build, live only in the project deps directory and be easy to configure. Also, decent performance would be a plus.

In python land, [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) would be an equivalent of the type of server I'm thinking of.

Comment: Werkzeug is a library, not a web server.

Comment: it happens to include a server

Comment: You can either manually install PHP, Apache, MySQL (not too difficult), or use some XAMP or WAMP package. Just make sure to set it very similarly to the production server because there are many configurations choices that can cause problems if they are set up differently on the production server. I also recommend to use the latest stable PHP release (I think 5.3) and don't use any deprecated features that are included just for legacy reasons. So register globals, short tags etc are a big no no. These are turned off in newer PHP releases by default so don't turn them back on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the best webserver for the dev environment is as close as you can come to *exactly* the webserver in production. PHP is a lot less 'stand-alone' in some cases then Python, and it prevents nasty errors and surprises when pushing code to the production server. All kinds of havoc can ensue when a $_SERVER array is just that essential bit different, or something runs as (fast)cgi instead of as a module.

Comment: so if you had to choose would you go with mod_php or fastcgi?

Comment: @dcolish depends on the task. I'd recommend mod_php as it's way more familiar.

Comment: High performance dedicated server: mod_php. Shared server (either projects or people): fastcgi with suexec.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, look at exactly how your production server(s) are setup and duplicate that exactly as your dev environment. If you can't, just use XAMPP/MAMP and try to stick fairly close to what your server has (compare phpinfo() dumps till you get them similar as regards extensions). The former is both better & much easier though, if you can access the server config files,

Answer (score 0):

Well, speaking of web servers, Apache is a state of art. Throw in a PHP module and you are set. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The web server is irrelevant for a *development environment*.

Whatever you like to use for your development: Eclpipse, NetBeans, Vim, xdebug, Firebug/FirePHP, "tail -f /var/log/syslog", phpTest,... all these can be used irregardless of whether you install, say, lightHttpd or Apache.

So, yes. As close to the production environment as possible is a good idea.